# Can I specify `refl`'s parameter explicitly in Agda?

Tags: agda, homotopy-type-theory, implicit-argument

I'm working on some proofs in Agda that, for educational purposes, explicitly use the path induction principle (which I've defined myself) rather than pattern matching. In the theoretical mathematical basis, the `refl` constructor can be written with an index $\mathsf{refl}_x$ to represent the proof of type $x=x$, as it is in fact a function $\mathsf{refl}:\prod_{a:A}(a=_A a)$ (taken from the HoTT book). I find it quite confusing when `refl`s are implicit so I'd love to be able to specify `x` myself.

Is it possible to achieve a similar behavior in Agda's type constructor, possibly with an alternate definition of equality? I'd expect something like `refl {x}` but that doesn't seem to be the way it's defined currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely can. Given the default definition of the identity type

```
data _≡_ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : A → Set a where
  refl : x ≡ x
```

we have that

```
refl : {a : Level} {A : Set a} {x : A} → Set a
```

So the reason that `refl {term}` does not have type `term ≡ term` is that you're trying to supply `term` as the *first* implicit argument to `refl`, which is meant to be a `Level`. To remedy this you can specify which implicit argument you're trying to give a value for:

```
refl {x = term}
```

This is equivalent to

```
refl {_} {_} {term}
```

Comment: Note that the standard library defines a pattern synonym precisely for this use case. You can write `erefl term` (the 'e' is meant to be a mnemonic for "explicit refl").

Comment: @gallais ah that's great! I was going to define my own, nice to see someone thought of it already haha.